# How to preserve thread-safety of a CopyOnWriteArrayList with a correct run() method implementation?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I am using an `ExecutorService` with a `fixedThreadPool`. I create threads by implementing the `Runnable` interface. In the `run()` method, I am calling a time consuming function (let's say `Thread.sleep()` for now) and finally add an element to a thread safe `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. I am submitting threads in a for-loop. At the end of the for-loop I shutdown the `ExecutorService` and await termination.

However, the number of elements in the list does not turn out to be the same as the number of loop-iterations. Where is my mistake in concurrency thinking?

Here is a code example for this problem:

```
public class TestProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> stringList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            executor.submit(new myThread(stringList));
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(stringList.size()));

    }
}

class myThread implements Runnable {

    CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> stringList;

    public myThread(CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> stringList) {
        this.stringList = stringList;
    }

    public void run() {
        String string = new String("test");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(myThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        stringList.add(string);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your program appears to be fundamentally correct. I could take a guess that you might be using the wrong way ExecutorService, but that would be just a guess. Could you, please, show us your source code, or a piece of it? That will certainly help us.

Comment: I have added a code example, which demonstrates this effect.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the correct use case for a CopyOnWriteArrayList. A Collections.synchronizedList around a plain ArrayList would be more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

You're just not giving it enough time to complete.  If you want to execute this serially you would need 1000 * 100 milliseconds, which is 100 seconds.  You are running it with four threads, so divide that by 4 and you get 25 seconds.  You only wait 10 seconds to complete.  Increase that to 26 seconds just to be safe and you should see your result.

The `ExecutorService#awaitTermination` will wait the `N` number of seconds to complete, if it doesn't complete it will simply return out and continue the execution.  To prove my point check the return value 
`System.out.println(executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));`

The better solution here, is to use a `new CountDownLatch(1000)`, have each Runnable task `countDown` after it adds to the list and finally have the main thread `await` completion.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of ExecutorService.shutdown says the following:

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are
>   executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no
>   additional effect if already shut down.
>
> This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete
>   execution. Use awaitTermination to do that.

This means that you indicate your ExecutorService that it must stop it's services. Thus, this method sets a flag which indicates that the ExecutorService will end soon, which allows the main thread to returns from this method without problems.

ExecutorService.awaitTermination, moreover, reads as follows:

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown
>   request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted,
>   whichever happens first.

This means that the main thread will be blocked inside the method, where it will only be returned when the tasks sent to ExecutorService finish. In both cases, the developer intends to end the ExecutorService function. But with awaitTermination, the developer is saying ExecutorService should be terminated regardless of their tasks have been carried out or not.

As each task takes at least 100 milliseconds to complete, no one will possibly be completed because ExecutorService has a tolerance of only 10 milliseconds for completion of all it's tasks.

There is no point in calling shutdown and awaitTermination at the same time (or preceded by another). According to your code, shutdown has no effect. If you want your tasks to become completed, and that ExecutorService is terminated without caring if your main thread will continue, just use shutdown. If you do not want your main thread to be blocked, and simply want to end with ExecutorService, use shutdownNow.

If, on the other hand, you want your main thread to wait for the execution of your tasks without a certain time to be specified, you may have to use Java Synchronizers. Some of Java Synchronizers are as follow:

- Latches
- FutureTasks
- Semaphores
- Barriers

For your case, I believe you can use [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Make a new CountDownLatch object have the number of tasks running on your ExecutorService. As they are completed, the count is decreased, and so, your main thread can expect completion and continue after all.

I hope you have understood and you can do what you want. If you have further questions, the documentation of CountDownLatch demonstrates perfectly how you can synchronize tasks. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In that code snippet one issue will be there.

```
executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Here it will wait for 10 seconds after that it will break.

You will try following snippet.

```
    while (true) {
        if(executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            break;
    }
```